# Interval of convergence and Stirling

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I need to find the interval of convergence of this power series $\frac{n^n}{n!}z^n$. I obtained the radius of convergence to be $\frac{1}{e}$, but I am having problems calculating the convergence at the end points. I tried using the Stirling formula, but i am not sure how to apply it formally. Using it for $z =\frac{1}{e}$ I can transform the sum to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$, which doesn't converge, but the Stirling approximation is a lower bound, so one over that would be an upper bound, so I am not sure how to do it formally. And I am also stuck for $z = -\frac{1}{e}$. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An exact version of Stirling formula for $n>0$ can be written as
$$ n! = \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\exp\frac{\theta_n}{12n}, \quad0<\theta_n<1. $$

So although Stirling formula is a lower bound, the relative error decreases to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so if you add any factor $>1$ to $\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$ in Stirling formula, it will eventually (for $n$ large enough) become an upper bound for $n!$.

Regarding $z=-1/e$, to use the alternating series test, we need to show that $a_n=\frac{(n/e)^n}{n!}$ eventually becomes decreasing monotonically.
$$ \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}\exp\left(\frac{\theta_{n+1}}{12(n+1)}-\frac{\theta_n}{12n}\right) > \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{12n}\right) = (1+\tfrac12n^{-1}+O(n^{-2}))(1-\tfrac{1}{12}n^{-1}+O(n^{-2})) = 1 + \tfrac{5}{12}n^{-1} + O(n^{-2}), $$
which eventually becomes $>1$.